# How to make the case for a parallel trends assumption in a within-person DiD with 1 pre-treatment time point 1 post-treatment time point?

Tags: repeated-measures, assumptions, research-design, segmented-regression, generalized-did

**Study design:**

Within a two-year period (2021-2022), both the people in the treatment group and the people in the control group did not receive the treatment of interest at time point #1, and only the people in the treatment group received the treatment at time point #2.

Time points #1 and #2 vary across people. So, one person may have time point #1 on January 1, 2021, and time point #2 on March 1, 2022, while another person may have time point #1 on April 1, 2021, and time point #2 on September 1, 2021. In other words, not only do time points #1 and #2 for different people take place at different times throughout the 2-year study period, but the number of days between the two time points also varies across people.

My outcome variable is the rate at which people engage in action z following the treatment, i.e. a person either engages in action z throughout their program involvement or not (if a person engages in action z they are coded 1 and if they don’t engage in action z they are coded 0). So, the outcome variable used in my DiD is an aggregate rate that ranges between 0 and 1.
The length of program involvement varies across time points as well as across people, i.e., for a given person, the length of program involvement during which the outcome is measured may be longer after time point #1 than after time point #2 (or vice versa), and the length of program involvement at each time point is longer for some people than for others. However, for each person, time point #2 is, by definition, *after* the end of program involvement following time point #1.

My within-person design ensures that the model basically “controls” for time-invariant individual-level factors (both observed and unobserved). On top of that, I will be able to control for various important observed time-variant factors, but obviously not for unobserved time-variant factors.

Now, I have the following questions:

1. **Does this design constitute a “regular” DiD or a staggered DiD?** I'm asking this because study participants were treated at different time points (e.g., one person may have both time points in 2021 whereas another person has both time points in 2022) - therefore it’s possible that the treatment effect fluctuates over time. A staggered DiD also assumes that once people receive the treatment, they remain treated throughout the observation period. I *think* this assumption is met because, as I mentioned above, I only measure whether people engage in action z throughout the program enrollment (i.e., if one person’s program length is 20 days, then their tracking period is also 20 days, and if another persons’ program enrollment is 180 days, then their tracking period is also 180 days).
2. **Should I control for covariates or use some type of propensity score method** (e.g., PSM or IPTW) to achieve covariate balance between the treatment and comparison group? (And would I also want to ensure that there’s covariate balance between observations made at time point #1 and time point #2?) I have a large number of variables I can control for, so I wonder whether I should create propensity scores so I can “throw the kitchen sink” at it, whether I should plug in the conceptually most important control variables, or whether I should use a Lasso algorithm to do the control variable selection for me. Finally, even though I use a within-person design, should I still use time-invariant person-level control variables in my model (e.g. gender)?
3. **Parallel trends assumption:** I wonder how I can make the case that the parallel trends assumption is met. That is, because I only have one time point before the intervention, I cannot inspect whether pre-intervention trends are parallel between the two groups. I also don’t think I can run a placebo test with a fake treatment group that was not affected by the intervention, or by using a fake outcome that would not be affected by the treatment. I only have two time points for the vast majority of people, so I cannot compare effects between people who were “not yet treated” versus people who were “never treated”. Does the fact that my DiD looks at within-person effects and that time points #1 and #2 are at different times across people mean that it is less likely that the parallel trends assumption is violated? In other words, to what degree can I make the case that controlling for all individual-level factors (by virtue of using a within-person design) and for many observable time point-specific factors will ensure that parallel trends assumption holds conditionally on these covariates? Are there any other conceptual arguments or statistical tests I can employ to make the case that the parallel trends assumption is likely satisfied?

Comment: Welcome. Do you have daily or monthly observations of participants?

Comment: I have at least 2 date-specific observations per person within an 18-month study period. So, one person could have t1 on 1/1/2021 and t2 on 3/1/2021, and another person could have t1 on 9/1/2020 and t2 on 6/1/2021. And so forth.

Comment: So you don’t have consecutive observations for each person? In other words, the time *in between* the first and second time period varies across persons as well?

Comment: Correct, the time between the first and the second time varies across people, but they *are* consecutive observations.

Comment: I am not understanding how they are consecutive time periods. One person may be observed in January, then their post-period is in March. Another may be observed in May, then again in September. My conception of consecutive is serial observations for each month over time (i.e., Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, etc.). To be clear, you don’t have that here, right?

Comment: Oh my apologies, I see now. Yes, you described my data structure correctly.